# Plotting covariance from amcl_pose in Matlab

Tags: matlab, navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl-pose, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recorded a bag-file and am trying to plot the `/amcl_pose/pose/covariance` matrix which has a message type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`. I followed [this](https://se.mathworks.com/help/ros/ug/work-with-rosbag-logfiles.html) tutorial on plotting data from topics, however, when I try:

```
bagselect = select(bag, 'Topic', '/amcl_pose');
msgs = readMessages(bagselect);
ts = timeseries(bagselect, 'Pose.Covariance');
```

I Get the error:

```
The Pose.covariance property does not exist for message type geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345932/plotting-covariance-from-amcl_pose-in-matlab/) by [fendrbud](https://answers.ros.org/users/47228/fendrbud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2020-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out I have to read the messages as structures as in [this example](https://se.mathworks.com/help/ros/ref/rosbag.html#d118e9299).

```
bSel = select(bag, 'Topic', '/amcl_pose');
msgStructs = readMessages(bSel, 'DataFormat', 'struct');
```

I am then able to read `amcl_pose` as a struct and can then extract the first covariance matrix by

```
msgStructs{1}.Pose.Covariance
```

I now have to iterate through all the matrices and concatenate them in order to plot their values.

---

Originally posted by [fendrbud](https://answers.ros.org/users/47228/fendrbud/) with karma: 48 on 2020-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-05**:
I've converted your comment to an answer as it would appear this is the answer.

To link it to my comment about the `covariance` field not being at the top-level of the message (but at `pose.pose.covariance`: it would appear `msgStructs{1}` contains the top-level message contents. So then `pose.covariance` does exist there.